# Need help accessing Apple APN server from a Windows vs2017 program

Tags: ios, vb.net, apple-push-notifications, x509certificate

Struggling with this for days. I'm in over my head. I developed an iOS enterprise app that I want to add Push Notifications to. I think I have the client side (iPhone) set up all right, but the Windows app (VB) I am developing to connect to the APNs server is giving me a lot of trouble.

Here's the very basic code I am using that I found somewhere on the internet, with the exception line shown:

```
 Using client As New TcpClient()
        client.Connect("gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com", 2195)
        Using networkStream As NetworkStream = client.GetStream()
            txtErrorMessages.AppendText("Client connected." & vbNewLine)

            Dim clientCertificate As New X509Certificate(FileSystem.CurrentDirectory & "/apns-dev-key.p12", "abc123")
            Dim clientCertificateCollection As New X509CertificateCollection(New X509Certificate(0) {clientCertificate})

            ' Create an SSL stream that will close the client's stream.
            Dim sslStream As New SslStream(client.GetStream(), False, AddressOf ValidateServerCertificate, Nothing)

            Try
                [exception thrown here] sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient("gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com", clientCertificateCollection, SslProtocols.Default, False)
            Catch ex As AuthenticationException
                txtErrorMessages.AppendText(String.Format("Exception: {0}", ex.Message) & vbNewLine)
                If ex.InnerException IsNot Nothing Then
                    txtErrorMessages.AppendText(String.Format("Inner exception: {0}", ex.InnerException.Message) & vbNewLine)
                End If
                txtErrorMessages.AppendText(String.Format("Authentication failed - closing the connection.") & vbnewline)
                client.Close()
                Return
            End Try
        End Using
    End Using
```

A google search brings up tons of different variations, but they are all apparently obsolete due to changes in the Push Notifications API over the years. I can't find anything that works, but this snippet at least gets me further than anything else has.

The exception:

[image: authentication exception]

I've tried a number of different variations on the .p12 file generated by the ID page on the Apple developer site, exported from the Mac's keychain, followed the steps from a number of different tutorials for converting to other formats (like .pem), or whatever, and nothing seems to work.

Interestingly, though, if I change the password string, the exception changes to `The specified network password is not correct`, which makes me think that it is at least recognizing the password.

Can anyone lead me out of this mess?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that I had overlooked loading the certificates into the development server, which is described here: https://arashnorouzi.wordpress.com/2011/04/13/sending-apple-push-notifications-in-asp-net-%e2%80%93-part-3-apns-certificates-registration-on-windows/